# Geting DataTime from database through Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC Web Application Im trying to Ajax call an action method to retrieve some datetime from the database, the problem is the value comes as **"/Date(386028000000)/"**

its a **DateOfBirth** actually which I m using a java script function to calculate the age:

```
function (DOB) {
         var birthday = +new Date(DOB);
    return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}
```

Anyway i can fix the **Date Format** and get only the date in a proper format or change the **Java-Script** method to accept the current format of the date value ?

Comment: if you need more advanced dateTime processing, have a look at [Momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

```
    var FixedDate = new Date();
    FixedDate .setTime(DOB.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
    return ~~((Date.now() - FixedDate) / (31557600000));
```

Answer (score 0):

### **[Click here to check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nf5x/27/)**

### **Sample Javascript/JQuery**

```
var = MyDate_String_Value = "/Date(386028000000)/"
var value = new Date
            (
                 parseInt(MyDate_String_Value.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
            );
var dat = value.getMonth() + 
                         1 + 
                       "/" + 
           value.getDate() + 
                       "/" + 
       value.getFullYear();
```

### **Result** - "3/27/1982"